# What field will we be remembered for developing?

Tags: mathematics, ancient-greece

I had a course on History of Mathematics this semester and it seemed that each civilization became known for developing a particular area of mathematics. For example, Arithmetic and Ancient Egypt/Babylonia, Geometry and Ancient Greece, Algebra and Islam, Analysis and northern Europe, etc.
 Is this the case at all, were those areas really more researched, or do we associate one with the other because it was the first time it was studied? If the former is true, what area/areas of mathematics do you think we'll be remembered for developing?

Comment: Unless we manage to seriously self-destruct somehow, I suspect the 20th through 23rd (my rough guess) centuries will be more remembered as when earth life morphed into some kind of [new form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity), somewhat akin to the [development of the first cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_of_cells). Perhaps if you limit your question to a particular country and a single recent decade, then an attempt might be possible in answering your question.

Comment: Not sure who "we" are, different countries, and even different universities within a country are remembered for different things. Poland for operator theory, for example, because of the Banach school. If "we" is supposed to be modern mathematics overall, algebraic geometry and algebraic topology seem to dominate judging by the number of Fields medals awarded in them relative to other areas.

Answer (score 3):

Once I've heard a lecture of David Kazhdan (a very prominent mathematician), who said the following:
"18th century was the century of Analysis, 19th century was a century of group theory, and 20th century was the century of cohomology".

I disagree with this, but just wanted to communicate his opinion.
(In general I think that such statements are meaningless. There was SOME geometry
in Egypt and Babylon, and very much arithmetic in the Ancient Greece, and it is somewhat questionable which civilization invented algebra, except the name. And so on.
Of course Kazhdan's statement is even more open to crriticism).

Comment: Sarkaria ([1996](https://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1384996), [p.  251](http://kssarkaria.org/List.htm)) brings water to this mill: “[Poincaré’s influence] can perhaps be gauged by this simple little fact: Out of all the Fields Medallists, with the exception of perhaps three or four, every one of them – irrespective of his domain: number theory, algebra, analysis,... – has used some *homology* in his work!! Perhaps not since the invention of the *calculus* has a single tool so strongly influenced mathematics as *homology*.”

Comment: I think this statement is incorrect: "except three or four".